# Require is not defined

Tags: javascript, html, nodejs

Estoy haciendo una aplicacion de node y soy nuevo en esto.
El caso es que estoy usando require() y se que nodejs es para el lado del servidor y no se va a ver en el navegador pero, si estoy usando apache por que sigue sucediendo este error?

Comment: estas intentando correr `nodeJS` en el navegador usando apache?

Comment: @Riven si usando xammp

Comment: `NodeJS` no te va a correr nunca en el navegador, debes correr tu codigo usando la terminal de comandos, el navegador no tiene utilidades de consola nativas del sistema que son las que usa `nodeJS` por eso es que no puedes usar `nodeJS` en el navegador. en vez de ello trata a hacer lo siguiente:

Comment: Primero abre una terminal y mira si esta instalado `nodeJS` con el comando: `node --v` si esto te imprime alguna version de node entonces puedes dirigirte al directorio en el que tienes tu `script` usando el comando `cd rutaATuArchivo/` una vez estes dentro de la carpeta solo debes ejecutar el comando `node nombreDeTuArchivo.js`.

Comment: @Riven gracias, yo ya lo he hecho, pero el problema es que es confuso el hecho de que node funcione en electron que es en base a chromium y no en un navegador y ahi es donde surge mi duda.

Comment: `Node` NO funciona en `electron`, es alrevez, `electron` funciona con **node**, chromium es una version alternativa de chrome, `electron` su modulo principal se ejecuta en `nodeJS` mientras que lo que es la vista (el cliente) enrealidad no lo ejecuta `nodeJS` si no `chromium`.